# Trisecting an angle

Tags: geometry

In [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Lm9EHhbJAY) it is stated that trisecting an angle is not possible with only a compass and a straight edge. Here's a way I came up with:

> Let the top line be A and bottom line be B, and the point intersecting P.
>   1. Use the compass and pick any length. Draw a point M n units from P on A. Use the compass again to draw a point N n units from P on B.
>   2. Connect M and N.
>   3. Since we know how to trisect a line, we can trisect it and get 3 equal distance line segments with 2 points in between.
>   4. Connect the 2 points to the point P.
>   5. Done.

This seems to work for all angles that are not 0 or 180 degrees.
Given that it is proven that it's not possible to trisect an angle with only compass and a ruler without marks, something must have been wrong in my steps but I can't see any. Where is my mistake?

Comment: and another +1 for the conclusion that you must have made a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let your angle be almost 180 degrees, so your two lines are almost coincident. The line $MN$ is also almost parallel to the lines, and trisecting that segment leads to very unequal "thirds" of the angle.

Comment: They are almost "parallel", but they aren't. With great precision trisecting the angle is still possible with this method.

Comment: No, using your method, the middle "third" is always larger than the outer two "thirds". The arc length of the circular segments are not proportional to the pieces of the chord.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Since the distance from the middle point to the middle segment is way closer than the other two, the angle in between would be much greater than the other two, so this method only works for small angles. Thanks.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 This does not work for small angles either.

Comment: @peterwhy - Oh by work I mean a good enough approximation... like how $y=x$ is a "good enough" approximation of $y=\sin{x}$ if $x$ is small.

Comment: An initial 135 degrees angle would also demonstrate the problem quite well. The resulting 3 angles would not be 45 degrees and it's easy to check visually (adding 2 of them would not be equal to 90 degrees)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: When people say that trisecting an angle is impossible, they're talking about doing it exactly. It's always possible to come up with approximate trisections that only use straightedge and compass, that come as close as you like to being a genuine trisection...

Answer (score 10):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the two points you added to $\overline{MN}$, as shown.

[image]

Consider $\triangle PMY$. Assuming your trisection construction to be valid, $\overline{PX}$ must *bisect* $\angle MPY$. By the [Angle Bisector Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), we have
$$\frac{|\overline{PM}|}{|\overline{PY}|} = \frac{|\overline{XM}|}{|\overline{XY}|} = 1$$
so that $\overline{PM}\cong\overline{PY}$. By the same logic, $\overline{PN}\cong\overline{PX}$. Thus, $M$, $N$, $X$, $Y$ are all equidistant from $P$.

See the problem?

Comment: Thanks for this proof using contradiction! By the way, what program did you use to create this nice illustration?

Comment: You're welcome. And I used [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org).

Comment: Nice, thanks.­­­­­

Comment: The OP HAS actually proved that it is possible to trisect an angle.  In particular, that is possible to trisect the angle $0$

Answer (score 7):

If $\angle APB= \alpha$, then middle angle (middle part) will have measure
$$
\beta = 2\arctan \left(\frac{\tan(\alpha/2)}{3}\right) {\Large\color{red}{\ne}} \dfrac{\alpha}{3}.
$$

A few examples:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\alpha & \beta & error\\
\hline
3^\circ & 1.000203^\circ & 0.0203\%\\
6^\circ & 2.001626^\circ & 0.0813\%\\
9^\circ & 3.005494^\circ &0.183\%\\
\hline
30^\circ & 10.207818^\circ & 2.078\%\\
60^\circ & 21.786789^\circ & 8.933\%\\
90^\circ & 36.869897^\circ & 22.899\%\\
\hline
\end{array}

When angles are small, then this method gives not bad **approximation**, but it **isn't** the **exact** way of trisection.

Comment: Numerical evidence trumps error.