# How to "push" a line segment to a arc?

Tags: vectors, circles

**Graph**:

[image]

There is a circle with a radius of 5, the center is O

There are two points A and B on the circle. OA and OB are vertical.

Connect A and B to form a line segment AB.

The arc between A and B is called arcAB.

**What I want**:

[image]

Imagine that there are countless points on the line AB (only 5 are marked in the graph), and I want to "push" these points to arcAB.

If you consider these 5 points as vectors, you can make them overlap with arcAB by scaling up the different values.

For example [1, 1.2, 1.414, 1.2, 1].

**Question**:

Is there any way to confirm this ratio?

Comment: *"If you consider these 5 points as vectors, you can make them overlap with arcAB by scaling up the different values."* Correct. Specifically: divide each vector by its length (which gives the vector *unit* length), and multiply by the radius of the arc (which gives the vector "radius" length).

Comment: @Blue it works! thank you, my hero.

Comment: When O, A, B are in a straight line (that is, the angle between OA and OB = 180 degrees) is a little problem.

Comment: *"When O, A, B are in a straight line [...] is a little problem."* That's often true of degenerate configurations. In the straight-line case, the notion of projecting the chord to the arc via the center is inherently broken, since all "direction vectors" become flat. For a strategy that works in all cases, you have to abandon the method you've illustrated for even the non-straightline case. Without context, it's not clear what would best serve your needs, but you might consider projecting, not from center $O$, but from the midpoint of the "other" arc of the circle. Does that interest you?

Comment: At first I thought this was the smart way. but when I tested it more and more, I found it was flawed. Actually you have solved my original question, I just don't know how to mark the comment as an answer.

Comment: I can post a proper answer. To be clear: you're satisfied with my first comment, correct? ... I'm not sure what you're saying is "flawed". Is it my suggestion that you project from the midpoint of the "other" arc? This works perfectly well to "push" a segment to an arc, and has the benefit of not breaking for a $180^\circ$ angle. (Indeed, it even works for angles larger than $180^\circ$.) The results don't match those of the origin-centered projection in your figure, but that's not a "flaw" ... it's a *fix*. ;)

Comment: 1. Your first comment has already answered my question.
2. "flawed" means that the curve divided by this method is not even.
3. If possible, I would love to hear about your new method.

Comment: 1 & 3. Okay. ... 2. Simply projecting a segment to an arc won't make even divisions (except at the midpoint)). Otherwise, trisecting a chord would be equivalent to trisecting an angle, [but it's not](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066037/409). If the goal is even divisions, you should say so. But the only way to *get* even divisions is to "abstractly" associate a pt $P$ on the chord to a pt $P'$ on the arc such that $|AP|/|PB]=|\stackrel{\frown}{AP'}|/|\stackrel{\frown}{P'B}|$. This association doesn't correspond to a classical geometric construction. I'll remark on this in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\bigcirc O$, let $\angle AOB=2\theta$. OP asks how to "push" chord $\overline{AB}$ to arc $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$, and proposes specifically the strategy of projecting from the center $O$, as shown with points $P$ and $P'$ in these figures:

[image] [image]

Formulating of the projection is simple: divide $\overrightarrow{OP}$ by its length, then scale it by the radius of the circle; ie,
$$\overrightarrow{OP'} = \frac{r}{|OP|} \overrightarrow{OP} \tag1$$
Less elegantly (but more-instructively), if we define $p := \dfrac{|AP|}{|PB|}$ (so that $P=\dfrac{A+pB}{1+p}$) as a parameter that ranges from $0$ (when $P=A$) to $\infty$ (when $P=B$), we can write
$$P' = \left(\;\frac{r (1 + p \cos2\theta)}{\sqrt{1 + 
 2 p \cos2\theta+p^2}}\;,\; \frac{r p\sin2\theta}{\sqrt{1+ 2 p \cos2 \theta+p^2}}\;\right) \tag2$$

Unfortunately, such a projection is problematic when $\angle AOB=180^\circ$, as shown in the second figure; all the vectors $\overline{OP}$ are "flat", so their projections will only land at $A$ or $B$ (point $O$ projects to itself). This is reflected in how $(2)$ reduces when $\theta=90^\circ$:
$$P' = \left(\;\frac{r (1-p)}{|1-p|}\;,\; 0\;\right) \tag{2'}$$

In a comment, I suggested an alternative.

Instead of projecting from $O$, project from the midpoint of the "other" arc of the circle ($M$ in the figures), as shown with points $Q$ and $Q'$. Here, defining $q := \dfrac{|AQ|}{|AB|}$, we can write
$$Q' =\left(\;\frac{r (1 + 2 q \cos\theta + q^2 \cos2\theta)}{1 + 
 2q\cos\theta + q^2}, \frac{2r q \sin\theta(1 + q\cos\theta)}{1 + 
 2 q\cos\theta+q^2}\;\right) \tag3$$
This strategy works even when $\angle AOB = 180^\circ$, as the $\theta=90^\circ$ form of $(3)$ is
$$Q' =\left(\;\frac{r (1-q^2)}{1+q^2}, \frac{2rq}{1+q^2}\;\right) \tag{3'}$$
which, by interesting coincidence, corresponds to the [Weierstrauss tangent-half-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution) parameterization of the (upper semi)circle. (Fun Fact: It's not a coincidence!)

---

OP has commented that the second projection (via $M$) is "flawed" because it doesn't divide the arc evenly. This is true: except when $Q$ is the midpoint (or an endpoint) of the chord, the projection doesn't transfer the chord ratio to the arc; ie, $|AQ|:|QB|\neq|\stackrel{\frown}{AQ'}|:|\stackrel{\frown}{Q'B}|$. But this is also true of OP's projection (via $O$).

Indeed, there is no "geometric construction" (in the classical sense) to get from every $P$ on the chord to the corresponding $P'$ on the arc such that $|AP|:|PB|\neq|\stackrel{\frown}{AP'}|:|\stackrel{\frown}{P'B}|$. In particular, if $P$ "trisects" the chord then $P'$ would have to *trisect* the arc, giving a trisection of $\angle AOB$ which is a [famously impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection) thing to accomplish via straightedge-and-compass techniques. (So, it's certainly impossible to accomplish via a simple projection from some given point. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066037/409) for a quick proof when the point is the center of the circle.)

If $P'$ is required to divide the arc the same way $P$ divides the chord, for every $P$ on that chord, then essentially the best one can do is to write
$$P' = \left(r \cos\frac{2p\,\theta}{1+p}, r\sin\frac{2p\,\theta}{1+p}\right) \tag4$$
although this lacks the sense of geometrically "pushing" the chord to the arc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume first that the circle is the circle of center $(0,0)$ and radius $R>0$ and passes through the points $A$ and $B$. Since $\frac{\vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||}$ is a unit vector, then $5\frac{\vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||}$ is on the circle and parallel to $\vec{v}$.

In the general case, you can use vector translation to move points so that the center is the origin, then use the inverse vector translation.